# How to restore saved transform when flipped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgaffinetransform

---

I persist a transform and a frame of an object.  When the app reloads I simply need to restore the frame and the transform on a new view.  You would think that you could simply set the frame and transform to the saved values, but you can't.  Doing so creates undesired results.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html

Says : "When you apply success transformations, the order matter. Rotating and then translating will give you a different result then translating and then rotating. This can bite you if you're not careful."

I only have transform problems when I save an transform that has been **FLIPPED & ROTATED**.  My save values are identical to the values that are applied to the restored view.

Actual Results:

When doing :

myNewView.frame = savedFrame

myNewView.transform = savedTransform

My view will shift down and to the right (out of place).

Can someone help me restore my transform in the proper order of operations?

Again, I have confirmed that my saved and loaded transform data is perfect, so I know its an order of operations problem, im just not smart enough to figure out what to do next :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To undo the saved transformation, you need the inverse transformation.  See the heading Stepping Back in the page you referenced.  Try:

```
myNewView.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(savedTransform);
```

An arbitrary matrix is not always invertible, but you are usually safe with an affine transformation.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Properties) are some special cases to watch out for.

In general, matrix inversion may lead to round-off errors, so if you need to do this repeatedly, you may need to use a different approach.

EDIT:

Having re-read the question, I suspect that the origin of the transformation may have changed.  When a rotation is involved, rotating about a different origin will appear to as an unexpected translation.  From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform), the origin is either the view's center, or the layer's anchor point.  I suggest checking these properties when you save the transform and see if they differ when you restore.

Comment: Sorry, I gave a good answer to the wrong question!  I'll have another look.

Comment: That was it! So for anyone who ever tries to restore position and transform, you need to restore it in this order:
myNewView.frame = mySavedFrame;
myNewView.center = mySavedCenter;
myNewView.transform = mySavedTransform;